# Gain and output impedance in a differential amplifier

Tags: amplifier, analog, gain

When looking at a differential amplifier:

Why does gain increase when the output impedance is increased?

For example, replacing a differential amplifier biased with resistors for an active load (higher output impedance).

Comment: Can you give a link to a datasheet for an example of the kind of amplifier you're asking about? Or a schematic if you're talking about an amplifier you might build yourself from components.

Comment: Viewing the diffpair as a transconductor, the output is current. With  higher rout, the delta_Vout = delta_I * *R, and delta_Vout becomes larger.